# How do I automatically add rows to a table in excel to make data match other table in same sheet

Tags: excel

I am currently comparing data from two different sources in an excel spreadsheet. My left table is missing a few entities and because the tables are sorted the same way. I have been simply adding rows to the first table to make the rows match up.

Ill use this image to describe what I need a little better:

[image: Sample table]

Consider these two different tables in the same worksheet. I would like a row to be inserted automatically above ID-5 in the first table to make it align with ID-row 5 in the second table. I would also like to do the same thing for ID row 8.

Is there an automatic process I could evoke in order to add rows until the data matches up?

Comment: To help you best, what's the purpose of doing so? Do you want blank rows in your table? F

Comment: Yes I want blank rows in my left table so that the data matches up based on the ID column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the right-hand pair of columns is comprehensive (say starting in C1), you might put, in E1 copied down to suit:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C1,A:A,0)),"")
```

This does not add or delete any rows but should match the left pair with the right pair. If the right pair is not comprehensive list of IDs then append one ID column to the other and delete duplicates on that column to create a complete list.